# Python creating pip package - module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setup.py

I am trying to create a python package to distribute my code. I am not getting any error in creating a package, and installing created package.

However, after installation when I am trying to import the package I am getting error `ModuleNotFoundError:`

Following is the code

**hello_world.py**

```py
class HelloWorld:
    def print_msg(self):
        print("Hello World")
```

**setup.py**

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name = "HelloWorld",
    version = "0.1",
    packages = find_packages(),
)
```

**create package**

```
▶ python setup.py bdist_wheel
running bdist_wheel
running build
installing to build/bdist.macosx-10.14-x86_64/wheel
running install
running install_egg_info
running egg_info
writing HelloWorld.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to HelloWorld.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to HelloWorld.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'HelloWorld.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'HelloWorld.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Copying HelloWorld.egg-info to build/bdist.macosx-10.14-x86_64/wheel/HelloWorld-0.1-py3.7.egg-info
running install_scripts
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.14-x86_64/wheel/HelloWorld-0.1.dist-info/WHEEL
creating 'dist/HelloWorld-0.1-py3-none-any.whl' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.14-x86_64/wheel' to it
adding 'HelloWorld-0.1.dist-info/METADATA'
adding 'HelloWorld-0.1.dist-info/WHEEL'
adding 'HelloWorld-0.1.dist-info/top_level.txt'
adding 'HelloWorld-0.1.dist-info/RECORD'
removing build/bdist.macosx-10.14-x86_64/wheel
```

**Installing package**

```
~/PycharmProjects/test_dist ▶ pip install dist/HelloWorld-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./dist/HelloWorld-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: HelloWorld
Successfully installed HelloWorld-0.1

~/PycharmProjects/test_dist ▶ pip freeze
HelloWorld==0.1
```

**Error While importing module**

```
>>> import HelloWorld
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'HelloWorld'
```

Comment: Is this just typo `class HelloWord:`?

Comment: @CodeRed yes, it's a typo. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is `hello_world.py`? Is it at the root folder adjacent to `setup.py`? Or in some subdirectory? I suspect the former. That means you don't have any packages so `find_packages()` returns an empty list so `setuptools` don;t package any code into the package.

Your `hello_world.py` isn't a packages (a directory with file `__init__.py`), it's a standalone module and such modules must be packed using `py_modules`. This is how you should write your `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = "HelloWorld",
    version = "0.1",
    py_modules = ['hello_world'],
)
```

Comment: both `hello_world.py` and `setup.py` files are directly into project folder. I made the changes you have suggested. however it's still giving the same error.

Comment: You cannot `import HelloWorld` if the module is named `hello_world`. Either `import hello_world` or `from hello_world import HelloWorld`.